# Is the call stack frame limit dependent on your ram or the language?

Tags: javascript, python, c, callstack

I'm doing a write up about the concept of the call stack and I want to touch on the limitations of the call stack in different languages.

I know there are ways to see how many frames can be on the call stack such as:

**Python**

```
import sys
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
```

**Javascript**

```
 let count = 0;
 const counter() {
     count++;
     counter();
 }
 
counter();
```

I'd also like to know the same for C. But my main question is whether this number is a number set by the language or if that number is totally dependent on how much ram the device has.

Comment: This usually isn't an aspect of a programming language. Do you mean the language implementation? I would think that it's a decision to be made, so it must be made by those writing an implementation, but then would also be limited by available resources on the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on a lot of things like the operating system, the device, and the amount of RAM.  In lots of compiled languages, the operating system lets you grow the stack until the OS decides it doesn't want to give you anymore.  In many embedded devices, hackers intentionally grow the stack beyond expected bounds in order to break into the device.